# Whole or part of the window is selected in Mac M1

Tags: intellij-idea, apple-m1, macos-monterey

I just installed IntelliJ in the Mac mini (M1 chip) and the whole window is selected which is wired.

[image]

I use macOS Monterey. How do I get rid of this?

PS: this may be just related to the Monterey OS as happening to the other places as well.

PS2: Even when I write in Chrome, this happens to me.

[image]

Comment: Seems similar to an accessibility feature of macOS

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov Do you know how I can turn this off? This is very annoying and I want to get rid of it.

Comment: Try disabling full keyboard access: https://i.imgur.com/6n3oCEp.png

Comment: wow, this solved the issue instantly that I was searching on the internet for hours. Please, write an answer so other people can find it more easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This blue border belongs to "Full keyboard access" feature, which has been reworked in macOS Moterey.
You can disable it in **Settings > Accessibility > Keyboard**:

[image]

See [this](https://www.macworld.com/article/351823/macos-monterey-full-keyboard-access-accessiblity-navigation-hardware-viewer-how-to.html) article on Macworld for additional info.